# Keyboard shortcut to access a function in a menu bar app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, menu-bar, shortcut

I have MacID on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.2 Public Beta) and my iPhone, and I'm trying to make a shortcut to MacID's "Send clipboard text" command. Since MacID is a menu bar app, though, the computer never sees it as the app in focus when thinking about app-specific commands.

I know how to assign keyboard shortcuts to app-specific commands. What I need is a way to make that happen for a command in a menu bar app (i.e. it'll never be the "active" app). How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try setting the shortcut to All Apps? (Can't test, on phone today)

Comment: @Tetsujin I just tried it and it didn't work. It was a nice suggestion, though!